# How to get react-native android splash screen

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, mobile, react-native

Could anyone help with setting a splash screen in react-native for Android devices?

I've easily set one up for iOS devices and works a treat, but i'm struggling to find a way to get one working on Android devices.

So far i've tried 2 node packages but they didn't work, i've added a "splash_screen.xml" file but I had no luck with that.

Cheers

Comment: I think there is no difference between iOS and Android due It should be handled by code written by devs. Could you share your code (a minimal example would be enough) to show us what could be going wrong in Android? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it on the native side of things:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/